# ElasticSearch query returned an error in script score - unexpected character '['

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use a document value `relevancy` to adjust the _score of ElasticSearch results but I cannot access it. I checked the mappings and the relevancy field is listed.
`"reason" : "unexpected character '[' on line (1) position (12)"`

query:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query":    "test", 
          "fields": [ "frecno", "item_id", "extended_desc", "mfg_part_no" ] 
        }
      },
      "script_score" : {
          "script" : {
            "lang": "expression",
            "source": "doc['relevancy']"
          }
      },
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
'
```

mapping:

```
{
    "products": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "@version": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extended_desc": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "frecno": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "item_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "mfg_part_no": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "relevancy": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the the script key to `"script": "doc['relevancy']"` and no longer received the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message doesn't seem to make much sense. I would verify the logic on your multi match query:

```
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "test", 
      "fields": [ "freqno", "item_id", "extended_desc", "mfg_part_no" ] 
    }
  },
```

In your mapping you have freqno as frecno. Additionally, does it make sense to match this field with your query? As your query is "test" but freqno is long, so basically you are trying to search an integer field with text. I tried doing the same and received errors.